# Docker start container: error creating overlay mount ... /merged: no such file or directory

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi4, home-assistant

I had an issue with docker running on a raspberry pi 4 and I purged all of it apart from the folder with the containers/images.
Reinstalled docker, run helloworld, runs ok. Installed portainer to manage the containers, several of them start but a particular one, homeassistant, doesn't

It reports

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ docker start homeassistant
Error response from daemon: error creating overlay mount to /var/lib/docker/overlay2/7c4732337e167e0f8178b8667bddc0393c2c1e4f7ffba5d68fe57379cc1de7c0/merged: no such file or directory
Error: failed to start containers: homeassistant
```

Here's the result of docker info

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ docker info
Client:
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 7
  Running: 4
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 3
 Images: 32
 Server Version: 19.03.8
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: <unknown>
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429
 runc version: dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 init version: fec3683
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 4.19.97-v7l+
 Operating System: Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: armv7l
 CPUs: 4
 Total Memory: 3.814GiB
 Name: raspberrypi
 ID: CS34:4SMJ:FTCR:T3O3:JVWH:LNEC:RWIE:2D7X:435Z:4WHM:UZZZ:CMS3
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No swap limit support
WARNING: No cpu cfs quota support
WARNING: No cpu cfs period support
```

Here are the contents of the overlay folder

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo ls /var/lib/docker/overlay2/7c4732337e167e0f8178b8667bddc0393c2c1e4f7ffba5d68fe57379cc1de7c0/
diff  link  lower  work
```

I've checked the overlay2 folder and indeed there's no merged folder. I've tried creating an empty one, but it gets deleted as soon as I attempt starting the container. What does this folder indicate when it comes to the container and how do I work around it? Ideally I would like to keep the container as otherwise I would have to set up the whole thing again.

Comment: Hey, did you solve the problem? is happening to me right now!

Comment: unfortunately, no
I had to redeploy the image and start afresh 
Ever since, I've been keeping backups